# Does document format change behaviour of Google bot in terms of SEO? Like /path and /path.htm .html .php

Tags: seo, googlebot

I was told to delete ".html" from web application links in order to be better seen by Google bot. So `example.com/path/to/resource.html` should be `example.com/path/to/resource`. I didn't find any document saying that format of the resource, placed in urls, has any influence as such. No matter if it's php, htm, html or any other aspx.

So, how is it? Does omitting the `.html`, or any other format, make any difference to Google bot?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the behaviour of a search engine service / asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No not at all. You don't get more or lose ranking because of that. It is not worth the effort.